# Implementing Transfer Learning using Pegasus for Text Summarization generating junk characters

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, transfer-learning

I've been trying to generate summaries using [Pegasus library](https://github.com/google-research/pegasus) and following the steps as mentioned -

1. Created Input Data  `.tfrecord` in `pegasus\data\testdata`
2. Created a function to return `transformer_params` named `test_transformers` (suppose)
3. Running  `python3 pegasus/bin/train.py  --params=test_transformer  --param_overrides=vocab_filename=ckpt/pegasus_ckpt/c4.unigram.newline.10pct.96000.model,batch_size=1,beam_size=5,beam_alpha=0.6 --model_dir=ckpt/pegasus_ckpt/xsum/model.ckpt-30000`
4. `python3 pegasus/bin/evaluate.py  --params=test_transformer  --param_overrides=vocab_filename=ckpt/pegasus_ckpt/c4.unigram.newline.10pct.96000.model,batch_size=1,beam_size=5,beam_alpha=0.6  --model_dir=ckpt/pegasus_ckpt/xsum/model.ckpt-30000`

However, I am facing this issue in outputs when I am generating text -

[image: Outputs Having Junk]

Is there some issue in the way its implemented or the way I'm running the python code in step 3 and 4?

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [link to the closed issue](https://github.com/google-research/pegasus/issues/109).

The reasons highlighted for this issue is :-

```
1. --model_dir is typically a directory instead of a particular checkpoint. 
   -> Try changing model_dir to actual model directory instead of checkpoint
2. It seems there are only 100 training steps. 
   -> Try changing "train_steps": 100
```